# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property salesGST has not been initialized

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

Json Server data show in android using retrofit2 and rxjava2 when parameter passing to inteface then give error.

```
class Sales : AppCompatActivity() {

    internal lateinit var api : APIInterface

    private var compositeDisposable : CompositeDisposable? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales)


        compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

       fetchYearData()
    }

  private fun fetchYearData(){

        val retrofit = APIClient.apIClient
        if (retrofit != null) {
            api = retrofit.create(APIInterface::class.java)
        }


   compositeDisposable!!.add(api.getSalesGSTData(1,1,"04/01/2018","31/03/2019")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe( { displaySalesGSTData(it.salesGST) },
                {

                    Toast.makeText(this,it.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


        }))



    }
```

Model Class SalesGSTList JsonObject after its success and after JSONArray and JSONObject.

SalesGSTList.kt

```
class SalesGSTList {

    val success : String = ""

    lateinit var salesGST : ArrayList<SalesGST>
}
```

SalesGST.kt

```
class SalesGST {

    var FYearID : Int = 0

    var Cmp_Name : String? = ""

    var GSTIN : String? = ""
}
```

Interface

```
@GET("SalesGST.php")
    fun getSalesGSTData(@Query("cid") cid : Int,@Query("fid") fid : Int,@Query("fd") fd : String,@Query("td") td : String) : Observable<SalesGSTList>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `lateinit` from line `lateinit var salesGST : ArrayList<SalesGST>` in `SalesGSTList`.

```
class SalesGSTList {

    val success : String = ""

    var salesGST : ArrayList<SalesGST>? = null
    // you can also use
    // var salesGST : ArrayList<SalesGST>  = ArrayList()
}
```

for more info visit [kotlin-when-to-use-lazy-or-lateinit](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/kotlin-when-to-use-lazy-or-lateinit/)

Comment: because `salesGST` is null if value is not assign to the variable. **FIRST** Kotlin gives you power to run **safe** and avoid NullPointerException. **SECOND** You can also wrap the code where you getting `salesGST` inside not null condition like `if(salesGST !=null){}`. **THIRD** you can use `var salesGST : ArrayList<SalesGST>  = ArrayList()` instead of `var salesGST : ArrayList<SalesGST>? = null`.

Comment: but i have create other model class declare Arraylist : lateinit var year : ArrayList<Year>. its successfully data get.

Comment: whenever you use `lateinit` property, you have to assign value to the variable otherwise it will throw error `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property has not been initialized`. SO better option is use `var salesGST : ArrayList<SalesGST> = ArrayList()` it will returns blank arraylist and never throw any error.

Comment: var salesGST : ArrayList<SalesGST> = ArrayList() its give null ArrayList